# Proving that a function is weakly lower semi continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-topology, semicontinuous-functions

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and $g : \mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}$ a monotonic increase function that is lower semi continuous. Then, I want to show that
$h := g(\|\cdot\|)$ is weak lower semi continuous.

I tried the following approach: take $\{x_n\}$ weakly converging to $x$. Then, given $\epsilon > 0$ there is $f\in X'$, $\|f\| = 1$ such that
$$f(x-x_n) + \epsilon > \|x-x_n\|.$$

Since $$\|x\| \leq \|x-x_n\| + \|x_n\|,$$
then, once $g$ is monotone and increasing,
$$g(\|x\|) \leq g(\|x-x_n\| + \|x_n\|) < g(f(x-x_n) + \epsilon + \|x_n\|).$$

**Note that in principle $f$ depends on $n$.**

But thinking carefully one sees that since $|f(x-x_n)| \leq 1$, then it has a convergent subsequence (Bolzano--Weierstrass). Which implies that $\lim\inf f(x-x_n) = 0$ indeed.

Therefore, note that there is $n_0$ such that for all $n > n_0$,
$$f(x-x_n) < \epsilon.$$
Since,
$$\lim\inf g(f(x-x_{\epsilon}) + \epsilon + \|x_n\|) = \lim_{N\to\infty}\inf_{n\geq N} g(f(x-x_{\epsilon}) + \epsilon + \|x_n\|),$$
for $N > n_0$,
$$\lim\inf g(f(x-x_{\epsilon}) + \epsilon + \|x_n\|) \leq \lim\inf g(2\epsilon + \|x_n\|).$$

Now one needs to handle with $\epsilon \to 0^+$. But since $g$ is lower semicontinuous, then
$$g(0) \leq \lim\inf_{\epsilon\to 0^+}g(\epsilon) \Rightarrow$$
given any $\delta > 0$ there is $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that for any $\epsilon <\epsilon_0,$
$$g(0) < g(\epsilon) + \delta.$$

Therefore, there is no $\delta > 0$ such that $g(\|x_n\|) \geq \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}g(2\epsilon + \|x_n\|)  + \delta,$ for some $n>0$.

Hence,
$$g(x) \leq \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\lim\inf (2\epsilon + \|x_n\|) \leq \lim\inf g(\|x_n\|).$$

Is this correct?